# Java decimal formatting using String.format?

Tags: java, formatting, decimal

I need to format a decimal value into a string where I always display at lease 2 decimals and at most 4.

So for example

```
"34.49596" would be "34.4959" 
"49.3" would be "49.30"
```

Can this be done using the String.format command?
Or is there an easier/better way to do this in Java.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You want java.text.DecimalFormat.

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00##");
String result = df.format(34.4959);
```

Comment: Follow the same example you will get the wrong result. You need to use the RoundingMode.DOWN for this particular example. Otherwise, it uses HALF_EVEN. No, negative though.

Answer (score 191):

Yes you can do it with `String.format`:

```
String result = String.format("%.2f", 10.0 / 3.0);
// result:  "3.33"

result = String.format("%.3f", 2.5);
// result:  "2.500"
```

Comment: This may not be the correct answer to the question asked, but it's the answer I came here to find. Thanks!

Answer (score 41):

Here is a small code snippet that does the job:

```
double a = 34.51234;

NumberFormat df = DecimalFormat.getInstance();
df.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
df.setMaximumFractionDigits(4);
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);

System.out.println(df.format(a));
```

Comment: No negatives, but your code fails for the very first example, given by the original poster. Need to use RoundingMode.DOWN, otherwise it uses HALF_EVEN by default, I suppose.

Answer (score 3):

java.text.NumberFormat is probably what you want.

Answer (score 2):

NumberFormat and DecimalFormat are definitely what you want. Also, note the `NumberFormat.setRoundingMode()` method. You can use it to control how rounding or truncation is applied during formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You want java.text.DecimalFormat