# Java: get input string and change the format

Tags: java

I am getting an input string containing digits with comma (,) separated like these formats

1) `X,X`

2) `X,XX`

3) `XX,X`

My desired format is `XX,XX`.

I want if I get the input string like in above 1,2,3 formats it should be formatted as my desired format `XX,XX`.

For example,

1) If I get a string in this format `1,12`. I want to put a zero before 1 like this `01,12`.

2) If I get a string in this format 1,1. I want to put a zero before and ofter 1 like this `01,10`.

3) If I get a string in this format `11,1`. I want to put a zero after the last 1 like this `11,10`.

Any help will be highly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: post what have you tried so far

Comment: possible duplicate of [java decimal String format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433958/java-decimal-string-format)

Comment: You want to just display this `String` or also use it inside a variable?

Comment: I am using comma not dot that decimal format will not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex pattern to format in your specific pattern using [Lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
(?=^\d,\d\d$)|(?<=^\d\d,\d$)|(?<=^\d,\d$)|(?=^\d,\d$)
```

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/uR8aG0/1)

Here we are using three combination of data as given by you and empty space is replaced by zero.

Sample code:

```
String regexPattern="(?=^\\d,\\d\\d$)|(?<=^\\d\\d,\\d$)|(?<=^\\d,\\d$)|(?=^\\d,\\d$)";
System.out.println("1,12".replaceAll(regexPattern, "0"));
System.out.println("1,1".replaceAll(regexPattern, "0"));
System.out.println("11,1".replaceAll(regexPattern, "0"));
```

output:

```
01,12
01,10
11,10
```

Answer (score 0):

Feed in your number to the function, and get the desired String result.

```
    public  static String convert(String s){
    String arr[] = s.split(",");

    if(arr[0].length()!=2){
        arr[0] = "0"+arr[0];
    }

    if(arr[1].length()!=2){
        arr[1] = arr[1]+"0";
    }

    return arr[0]+","+arr[1];

}
```

But it only works in the format described above.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to print these strings, you could use the format method, and leading and trailing zeroes.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Object[] splitted = input.split(",");
System.out.println(String.format("%2s,%-2s", splitted).replace(' ','0'));
```