# Big decimal Conversion with roundup value

Tags: java, bigdecimal

i have a double value Such as

```
Double doubleValue=0.0001;
```

trying to print this gave me an output as `1.0E-4`

So I tried BigDecimal to value of this as.

`BigDecimal.valueOf(doubleValue)` which ended up giving output as "0.00010".

can anyone let me know how would I get a round up value as "0.0001".( no end trail of 0 after 1)

Comment: possible duplicate of [java decimal String format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433958/java-decimal-string-format)

Comment: it rounds up as 0 for 0.0001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try code similar to following

```
Double doubleValue=0.0001;    
DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("##.0000");
String formattedValue = f.format(doubleValue);
BigDecimal bigDecimalValue = new BigDecimal(formattedValue);
bigDecimalValue.stripTrailingZeros();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: but in case of input as  0.01 this returns output as 0.0100

Comment: @Kumar Yes, that true. I thought you were looking to keep till 4 decimal places

Comment: am sry for not making it clear.... I would need precision max of 4.. and no end trails of 0 for the value.

Comment: @Kumar Have you tried my updated answer? It should do the job -- precision max of 4 and no end trails of 0 for the value

Answer (score 1):

Are you printing with println? You should use printf to format your output.

```
        Double d = 0.000100;
        System.out.printf("%.4f",d);
```

The following will print "0.0001"

Hope this helps!