# Change String to Decimal in TextView Android

Tags: android

```
public void addDataListViewShowAllNotes(){
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String idUser = extras.getString("IdUser");
    Cursor cursor = db.getDataTableNote(Integer.parseInt(idUser));
    String form[] = new String []{db.KEY_CONTENT_NOTE, db.KEY_TYPE_NOTE, db.KEY_DATE_CREATE_NOTE, db.KEY_MONEY};
    int to[] = new int[] {R.id.textView_ContentNote, R.id.textView_TypeNote, R.id.textView_DateCreateNote, R.id.textView_MoneyNote};
    dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item_note, cursor, form, to, 0);
    ListView listViewManagePage = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_ManagePage);
    listViewManagePage.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}
```

Here is my method which I use to add data to my ListView.

```
private String textOutput(String s){
    Locale loc = Locale.getDefault();
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(loc);
    Double money = new Double(s);
    s = nf.format(money);
    return s;
}
```

Here is method which i use to change my text to number like money. 
Example 
"1000000" -> " 1,000,000.
But when i set method textOutput on

```
  String form[] = new String []{db.KEY_CONTENT_NOTE, db.KEY_TYPE_NOTE, db.KEY_DATE_CREATE_NOTE, textOutput(db.KEY_MONEY)};
```

The text i get is "money". It's name of column in database.
So how can i get my data in this column to use it.

Please help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java decimal String format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433958/java-decimal-string-format)

Answer (score 1):

`db.KEY_MONEY` refer to name of column which is `money` instead of value in db.

To show formatted data for `money`  column in `ListView` row using `SimpleCursorAdapter`, need to call `setViewBinder` for ListView adapter. like:

```
    dataAdapter.setViewBinder(new ViewBinder() {
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
            if (columnIndex == cursor.getColumnIndex(db.KEY_MONEY)) 
                    String moneyStr = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    TextView textView = (TextView) view;
                    textView.setText(textOutput(moneyStr));
                    return true;
             }
             return false;
        }

});
```